# How do I get rid of the $x$ in the (Epsilon-Delta-Definition)

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> $f(x)= \left\{
> \begin{align} 2x+1 \quad \text{if } x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
>  -2x^2+3x+4 \quad  \text{if } x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{align} \right.$
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous in $x_0=-1$

**Here's my attempt:**

**(i) $x\in \mathbb{Q}$**

For every $\varepsilon >0$, find $\delta_1>0$, such that for all $x_0, x\in \mathbb{Q}$:
$|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon $

$\Leftrightarrow  |x+1|<\delta_1 \implies  |2x+2|<\varepsilon$

Since $|2x+2|=2|x+1|<\varepsilon$, choose $\delta_1 := \varepsilon /2$.

**(ii) $x\notin \mathbb{Q}$**

For every $\varepsilon >0$, find $\delta_2 >0$, such that for all $x,x_1\notin \mathbb{Q}$ gilt:

$|x+1|<\delta \implies |-2x^2+3x+5|<\varepsilon $

We have $|-2x^2+3x+5|=|-(x+1)\cdot (2x-5)|=|x+1|\cdot |2x-5|<\delta \cdot |2x-5|$.

***How do I get rid of the $x$?***

Comment: $-2x^2+3x + 5= (x+1)(-2x+ 1)$  But if $\delta < \frac 14$, say, so that $-1.25 < x < -.75$ and $2.5<-2x+1<3.5$ so $|(x+1)(-2x+1)|=|x+1||-2x+1| < |x+1|*3.5$ so just make sure when it comes to finding your delta you restrict it to be less than $\frac 14$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

when $|x+1|<\delta$ then for sufficiently small $\delta>0$ we have $$6<|2x-5|<8$$

Comment: so $\delta \cdot |2x-5|<8\delta$?

Comment: Yes. That's correct and you can choose $\epsilon=8\delta$

Comment: So I would have to choose $\delta :=1/8\varepsilon$?

Comment: Actually you should take e.g. $\delta={\epsilon\over 8}$

Answer (score 1):

In general if you get something in terms of $|something| < c*\delta + k*\delta^2$ you can presume that if $\delta < 1$ then $\delta^2 < \delta$ and you have $c*\delta + k*\delta^2 \le c*\delta + k*\delta = \delta(c+k)$.

======

If $|x + 1| < \delta$ and $x$ is rational then $|f(x) - f(-1)| = |2x + 1 - (-1)| = |2x+2| = 2|x+1|< 2\delta$.

If $x$ is irrational then $|f(x) -f(1)| =|-2x^2 + 3x +4 -(-1)|=|-2x^2 +3x +5| = |x+1||5-2x|  < |5-2x|\delta$.

Now $|x+1| < \delta$ means

$-\delta < x+1 < \delta$

$-1 -\delta < x < -1+\delta$

$2-2\delta < -2x< 2+2\delta$ and

$7-2\delta < 5-2x < 7+2\delta$.  If we presume $\delta < 3.5$ we have

$0 < 5-2x = |5-2x| < 7+2\delta$ and so

$|f(x) - 1| = |x+1||5-2x|<|5-2x|\delta < (7+2\delta)*\delta =7\delta + 2\delta^2$.

If we presume $\delta < 1$ then we can either reason $7+2\delta < 9$ or that $\delta^2 < \delta$ so $2\delta^2 < 2\delta$.  Either way.

$|f(x) -f(1)|< 9\delta$.

So for any $\epsilon > 0$ if we set $\delta = \min(1, \frac {\epsilon}9)$ then

If $|x-(-1)|< \delta\le \frac {\epsilon}9\$ and $x$ is rational then

$|f(x) -f(-1)|= 2|x+1| < 2\delta \le \frac {2\epsilon}9 < \epsilon$.

If $x$ is irrational then

$|f(x) - f(-1)|=|x+1||5-2x|<|x+1|*9 \le 9\frac {\epsilon}9=\epsilon$.

In general, restricting $\delta < 1$ was not as tight as we could do.  We could restrict $\delta < \frac 1n$ let $\delta =\min(\frac 1n,\frac {\epsilon}{7+\frac 2n})$ will do for any $n$ but... why go through the trouble.